# Web Scraping and POST Request Issue: Unable to Retrieve Expected Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

I am currently working on a Python script using the `requests` library and `BeautifulSoup` for web scraping. The goal is to retrieve specific information from the website "https://letmepost.com/check-da-pa," particularly the DA (Domain Authority), PA (Page Authority), Spam score, Age, Expiring At, and IP address for a given domain. However, despite successfully obtaining a response, the data retrieved is not as expected.

I have shared my code, which includes handling the X-CSRF-TOKEN and sending a **POST** request with the necessary payload. However, the output I receive is just the domain "cnn.com" instead of the expected structured data, which includes the DA, PA, Spam score, Age, Expiring At, and IP.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

session = requests.Session() 
r = session.get('https://letmepost.com/check-da-pa', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

script_tag = soup.find("script", string=lambda text: text and "X-CSRF-TOKEN" in text)

if script_tag:
    token_pattern = r"'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '(.*?)'"
    csrf_token_match = re.search(token_pattern, script_tag.string)

    if csrf_token_match:
        csrf_token = csrf_token_match.group(1)
        print(f"CSRF Token: {csrf_token}")
    else:
        print("CSRF Token pattern not found in script content.")
else:
    print("Script tag with 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' not found.")


data = "prothomalo.com"

data_payload = {
    "domains ": data,
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token
}

# Existing data_payload
data_payload = {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token
}

# Adding new data to data_payload
data_payload["listen"] = "4OdeyKA6Sku1ff86NqkAibxXGf4kfOQUcbepB84U"
data_payload["secret"] = "PNxcg1LI9331xX7"
data_payload["urls"] = "prothomalo.com"
data_payload["fromBrowser"] = "1705462709623"
data_payload["timestamp"] = "1705462686"
data_payload["direct"] = True  # Assuming you want to add a boolean False, not the string 'false'

# The data_payload now contains the additional data
 
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token
}

url = "https://letmepost.com/check-da-pa"

response = session.post(url, data=data_payload, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)

import pandas as pd
result = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(result)
```

[image]
I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or corrections to my code that might help me retrieve the desired information accurately. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: The site's protected by CloudFlare. So, I don't think you'll get anything with pure `requests`.

Comment: @baduker

Could you please inform me of the possible solution?

Comment: Either use `selenium` or check if the site has an API.

Comment: @baduker

I am obtaining the output with Selenium, but the process is slow. I need to enhance its speed by using the requests library.

Comment: You *won't* get anything with `requests`. There's CloudFlare there and reCAPTCHA. Better to get the data in a slow way than have no data, no?

Comment: @baduker
Are you certain? What steps should I take to expedite the process? If I use selenium!

Comment: It's true that the site is protected by Cloudflare, as mentioned by @baduker. However, I can't even see how the content is being loaded in the developer tools.

Comment: `baduker` and `robots.txt`
Thank you so much for your information

Comment: Putting a bounty on the question won't help you much, IMHO. I'm pretty sure you can't bypass both CloudFlare and reCAPTCH with good old plain `requests`. If you're already getting data with selenium you might be better off optimizing your working solution.

Comment: Can you see how the content of that table is being produced through Chrome developer tools? Sadly, I can't. I should still be able to see the network activity for that request in developer tools even when the site is CloudFlare and reCAPTCH protected, right, @baduker? How can I do that?

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib As others have said, this likely isnt possible without a tool more sophisticated than Requests or bs4, are you willing to accept a Selenium solution? I see you have one but complained it was slow- how fast do you need it to be?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, that page is protected by both Cloudflare and (randomly) ReCaptcha.

IDK how to do it in Python, but in PHP with the [chrome-php library](https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
use function var_dump as d;
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$chromiumPath = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser';
function dd(...$args): void
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace(0, 2);
    $file = $trace[0]['file'];
    $line = $trace[0]['line'];
    echo "dd {$file}:{$line}: \n";
    var_dump(...$args);
    die();
}
$factory = new \HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory($chromiumPath);
$browser = $factory->createBrowser(
    [
//        'headless' => false,
    ]
);
$page = $browser->createPage();
$page->navigate("https://letmepost.com/check-da-pa")->waitForNavigation();
$page->evaluate('document.querySelector("#urls").value = ' . json_encode('cnn.com'));
$page->mouse()->find('#btnTransferDomain')->click();
// <tbody id="bulk-da-pa-checker-results"><tr><th scope="row">1</th><td class="td-wrap"><a href="http://cnn.com" target="_blank">cnn.com</a><a></a></td><td>95</td><td>82</td><td>1</td><td>30Y, 128D</td><td>2027-09-21</td><td>151.101.67.5</td></tr></tbody>
for(;;){
    $results = $page->evaluate('document.querySelector("#bulk-da-pa-checker-results")?.innerHTML')->getReturnValue();
    if($results && !str_contains($results, 'No Data yet') && !str_contains($results, 'Loading...')){
        break;
    }
    sleep(1);
    try{
        $recaptcha = $page->mouse()->find("#recaptcha-anchor > div.recaptcha-checkbox-border");
    }  catch (\Exception $e){
        $recaptcha = null;
    }
    if(!$recaptcha){
        try{
            $recaptcha = $page->mouse()->findElement(
                // XPathSelector
                new HeadlessChromium\Dom\Selector\XPathSelector(
                    '//iframe[@title="reCAPTCHA"]'
                ),
            );
        }  catch (\Exception $e){
            $recaptcha = null;
        }
    }
    if($recaptcha){
        $recaptcha->click();
        sleep(1);
        $page->mouse()->find('#btnTransferDomain')->click();
    }
}
// <table class="table-font table table-hover table-fixed"> <thead> <tr> <th>#</th> <th class="sort" data-sort="u" data-mode="up">Domain <i class="fas fa-chevron-down inactive sort-obj"></i></th> <th class="sort" data-sort="d" data-mode="up">DA <i class="fas fa-chevron-down inactive sort-obj"></i></th> <th>PA</th> <th class="sort" data-sort="s" data-mode="up">Spam <i class="fas fa-chevron-down inactive sort-obj"></i></th> <th>Age</th> <th class="sort" data-sort="de" data-mode="up">Expiring At <i class="fas fa-chevron-down inactive sort-obj"></i></th> <th class="sort" data-sort="i" data-mode="up">IP <i class="fas fa-chevron-down inactive sort-obj"></i></th> </tr> </thead> <tbody id="bulk-da-pa-checker-results"><tr><th scope="row">1</th><td class="td-wrap"><a href="http://cnn.com" target="_blank">cnn.com</a><a></a></td><td>95</td><td>82</td><td>1</td><td>30Y, 128D</td><td>2027-09-21</td><td>151.101.195.5</td></tr></tbody> </table>
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($results);
$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$da = $tds[1]->textContent;
$pa = $tds[2]->textContent;
$spam = $tds[3]->textContent;
$age = $tds[4]->textContent;
$expires = $tds[5]->textContent;
$ip = $tds[6]->textContent;
$results = compact('da', 'pa', 'spam', 'age', 'expires', 'ip');
d($results);
```

works the first 20 invocations or so and prints

```
hans@DESKTOP-EE15SLU:~/projects/misc$ time php test2.php 
array(6) {
  ["da"]=>
  string(2) "95"
  ["pa"]=>
  string(2) "82"
  ["spam"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["age"]=>
  string(9) "30Y, 128D"
  ["expires"]=>
  string(10) "2027-09-21"
  ["ip"]=>
  string(11) "151.101.3.5"
}
^C

real    0m10.008s
user    0m0.029s
sys 0m0.000s
```

and amazingly, to beat the the first couple of reCaptcha challenges, the random click() actually does the trick! (I'm surprised myself that it actually worked.. at least the first 20 times or so)

after that however, you'll get
[image]

and.. there are [ways to bypass it](https://github.com/imagetyperz-api/imagetyperz-api-php), but i'm giving up at this point.